# mist unable to upload smart contract with testrpc

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts

I am struggling to deploy a simple contract on mist.

I am using testrpc which shows all the accounts ans balances properly.

But when I deploy the contract it gives error:

> Unable to calculate gas

My mist and geth version are updated to latest.

Please find below the screenshot for error, it keeps on saying unable to estimate gas.

Could find this issue being reported at various places but does not address solution.

[image]

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm experiencing the same.

Comment: no not yet , still waiting for solution

Comment: I get similar errors when just trying to send Ether form one account to another. When clicking the "SEND TRANSACTION" I get "Account not found"

Comment: @udibr it may be possible that both accounts that you are using may be of different network , like the source account may on different network and destination account on different network